# Date validation error ("Split" not recognized)

Tags: c#, arrays, string, validation, date

I am busy writing code to validate a date entered via a textbox.
I experienced the following error with regards to `date.Spilt('/')`:

> "'string' does not contain contain a definition 'Spilt' and no extension method 'Spilt' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assemble reference?)"

I entered the `System.Char[]` and the `System.String[]` reference but C# did not recognise them. Here is my code below:

```
//validateDate function returns true/false for entered date
private bool validateDate(string date)
{
    try
    {
        string [] dateParts = date.Spilt('/');
        //creates new date from spilt parts
        DateTime testDate = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(dateParts[2]),
                                         Convert.ToInt32(dateParts[0]),
                                         Convert.ToInt32(dateParts[1]));
        return true;     
    }
    catch
    {
        //if no-date entered return false
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the error message. It's `split`. You typed `spilt`.

Comment: You might find it simpler to do with a regex: "[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+"

Comment: spilt:  past participle, past tense of spill (Verb). No use crying over spilt strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `split` instead of `spilt`

Also have you heard of `DateTime.TryParse` and `DateTime.TryParseExact`?

Comment: Haha I spelt it wrong. Pretty dumb of me. Thanks!